# GraphViz temporal ordering of nodes

Tags: graphviz, graph-visualization

I'm new to graphviz and have generated a graph that contains temporal constraints. That is, the order of nodes from left to right matters, but only locally. Here's the ruleset I'm trying to enforce:

1) Only and all 'box'-shaped nodes should be at the bottom of the graph. These represent terminal nodes.

2) Any rule at a 'doublecircle'-shaped node has temporal constraints (i.e. ordering matters).

Here's an attempt of enforcing these rules:

```
digraph G {
0 [shape=box, fillcolor=lightgrey, style=filled, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
1 [shape=box, fillcolor=lightgrey, style=filled, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
2 [shape=box, fillcolor=lightgrey, style=filled, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
3 [shape=box, fillcolor=lightgrey, style=filled, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
4 [shape=box, fillcolor=lightgrey, style=filled, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
5 [shape=box, fillcolor=lightgrey, style=filled, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
6 [shape=box, fillcolor=lightgrey, style=filled, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
7 [shape=box, fillcolor=lightgrey, style=filled, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
8 [shape=box, fillcolor=lightgrey, style=filled, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
9 [shape=doublecircle, fillcolor=palegreen3, style=filled, color=blue, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
9 -> 0 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
9 -> 2 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
{
  rank=same;
  0->2[color=white]
  rankdir=LR;
}
10 [shape=doublecircle, fillcolor=palegreen3, style=filled, color=blue, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
10 -> 9 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
10 -> 5 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
{
  rank=same;
  9->5[color=white]
  rankdir=LR;
}
11 [shape=doublecircle, fillcolor=palegreen3, style=filled, color=blue, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
11 -> 4 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
11 -> 10 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
{
  rank=same;
  4->10[color=white]
  rankdir=LR;
}
12 [shape=doublecircle, fillcolor=palegreen3, style=filled, color=blue, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
12 -> 10 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
12 -> 11 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
{
  rank=same;
  10->11[color=white]
  rankdir=LR;
}
13 [shape=doublecircle, fillcolor=palegreen3, style=filled, color=blue, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
13 -> 4 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
13 -> 9 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
{
  rank=same;
  4->9[color=white]
  rankdir=LR;
}
14 [shape=doublecircle, fillcolor=palegreen3, style=filled, color=blue, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
14 -> 26 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
14 -> 8 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
{
  rank=same;
  26->8[color=white]
  rankdir=LR;
}
15 [shape=doublecircle, fillcolor=palegreen3, style=filled, color=blue, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
15 -> 12 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
15 -> 13 [penwidth=3, weight=3]
{
  rank=same;
  12->13[color=white]
  rankdir=LR;
}
26 [shape=circle, fillcolor=palegreen1, style=filled, color=blue, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
26 -> 12[label = "0.50", penwidth=2.0, weight=3 ]
26 -> 15[label = "0.50", penwidth=2.0, weight=3 ]
}
```

From the ruleset, node 9 should have 0 as the left child and 2 as the right child, and so forth. This graph also does not enforce that all 'box;-shaped nodes should be at the bottom of the graph. Is it possible to build such a graph with GraphViz?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure how you would like this graph to look, but I have made an attempt. All boxes are at the bottom, this is done using a cluster subgraph (you can change the styling if you do not like the box). To prevent the edges from "special" edges (white in your code, red in mine because the background is also white) from interfering with the ordering, I specified a `constraint = false` on those edges. Let me know if this helps.

The code:

```
digraph G {
    subgraph clusterSquares {
        rank = same
        node [shape=box, fillcolor=lightgrey, style=filled, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
        0; 1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8;
    }
    {
        node [shape=doublecircle, fillcolor=palegreen3, style=filled, color=blue, ranksep=0.5, nodesep=0.5]
        edge [penwidth=3, weight=3]
        9 -> { 0; 2; }
        10 -> { 5; 9; }
        11 -> { 4; 10 }
        12 -> { 10; 11; }
        13 -> { 4; 9; }
        14 -> { 26; 8; }
        15 -> { 12; 13; }
        26 -> { 12; 15; }
    }
    {
        edge [color = red, constraint = false]
        0 -> 2
        9 -> 5
        4 -> 10
        10 -> 11
        4 -> 9
        26 -> 8
        13 -> 13
    }
}
```

The resulting image:

[image]